# Is it possible to change the precision of the np.add() function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, addition

I would like to add the following two arrays:

```
[1.+1.j 2.+2.j 3.+3.j]
[-2.07818374e-10+0.00000000e+00j -1.55863780e-10+2.59772967e-11j
  0.00000000e+00+1.55863780e-10j]
```

When I use the add() function, I get

```
[1.+1.j 2.+2.j 3.+3.j]
```

However, I want to get

```
[0.9999999997921816+1j 1.9999999998441362+2.0000000000259774j 3+3.0000000001558638j]
```

I get the desired result if I write my own add function that 1.) initializes a zero array 2.) uses a for loop to add the relevant positions together 3.) replaces the zeros with the sums. Surely there must be a way to do this without writing a new function though? This is important because I need to be able to correctly add such sums for arbitrarily sized arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define your 'arrays' as lists, not numpy arrays:

```
In [335]: alist1 = [1.+1.j, 2.+2.j, 3.+3.j] 
     ...: alist2 = [-2.07818374e-10+0.00000000e+00j, -1.55863780e-10+2.59772967e-11j, 
     ...:   0.00000000e+00+1.55863780e-10j]                                                   
In [336]: alist1                                                                              
Out[336]: [(1+1j), (2+2j), (3+3j)]
In [337]: alist2                                                                              
Out[337]: [(-2.07818374e-10+0j), (-1.5586378e-10+2.59772967e-11j), 1.5586378e-10j]
```

Add then with a list comprehension.

```
In [338]: [i+j for i,j in zip(alist1,alist2)]                                                 
Out[338]: 
[(0.9999999997921816+1j),
 (1.9999999998441362+2.0000000000259774j),
 (3+3.0000000001558638j)]
```

with `np.add`, the lists are first turned into arrays (hidden):

```
In [339]: arr = np.add(alist1, alist2)                                                        
In [340]: arr                                                                                 
Out[340]: array([1.+1.j, 2.+2.j, 3.+3.j])
```

but when we convert the array to a list we get the same result as the comprehension.

```
In [341]: arr.tolist()                                                                        
Out[341]: 
[(0.9999999997921816+1j),
 (1.9999999998441362+2.0000000000259774j),
 (3+3.0000000001558638j)]
```

or looking at one element by itself:

```
In [342]: arr[0]                                                                              
Out[342]: (0.9999999997921816+1j)
```

The values in [340] that bother you are just display values, not the underlying numerical values. The display values are rounded off.

```
In [343]: arr.dtype                                                                           
Out[343]: dtype('complex128')
```

We can change that display with `printoptions`:

```
In [350]: with np.printoptions(precision=17): print(repr(arr))                                
array([0.9999999997921816+1.j                ,
       1.9999999998441362+2.0000000000259774j,
       3.                +3.0000000001558638j])
```